# Effects of hourglass button in Android P easter egg

Tags: 9.0-pie, easter-egg

In the Android P easter egg, PAINT.APK, there is a button in the toolbar that looks like an hourglass. Clicking it rotates it, but it appears to have no effect. What effects do the hourglass button in the Android P easter egg have?

[image: Hourglass]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found out that when the hourglass is vertical, it makes the colors fade over time. But when it is horizontal, the colors do not fade.

Purple sitting 3 minutes with hourglass vertical on the left
Purple sitting 3 minutes with hourglass horizontal on the right[image]